# Wkhtmltopdf knp snappy converting to PDF with wrong symbols for Urdu language

Tags: php, symfony, wkhtmltopdf, urdu, knp-snappy

all! I'm using wkhtmltopdf knp snappy in my project for generating of PDFs from html template.
For Urdu language I came across an issue, that it is not generated accurately. Instead of some characters there is white squares. But in generated html page (before converting) everything works fine. Can you help me, please, and tell, how to fix it?

I've already tried changing of encoding for html in head section, adding encoding to wkhtmltopdf configs and testing fonts (fonts worked in html generated page but were ignored by pdf for some reason)

Comment: Is it possible that the font you are currently using lacks the characters you are attempting to display in the PDF? Consider using Arial Unicode this may solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use absolute path instead of relative.
Maybe you have used import command in css with relative path for font config lines.

Try to write your font configs inline directly in your html page.